# Modifying/Using an open source software to use in my open source application

Tags: ms-pl

I am working on creating a open source software that will be hosted at github. In that software I would like to use another open source component available at codeplex under Ms-Pl license. My questions are:

- Do I need to contact the author of that component at codeplex to use it?
- I will have to make some changes in original component to make it compatible with my application. Am I allowed to do that?

Comment: Welcome to Open Source! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do I need to contact the author of that component at codeplex to use it?

Nope. This can be a nice thing to do, but not required.

> I will have to make some changes in original component to make it compatible with my application. Am I allowed to do that?

Yes. If the license allows it (all open source definition "compliant" licenses allow it), you are allowed to do it.
The MsPL is a fairly permissive license as you can see [here](https://enterprise.dejacode.com/license_library/Demo/ms-pl/#license-requirements) with rather simple and readable terms.